# BackGround Notification Data Fetch

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

So What i am essentially trying to do is Send a notification from firbase gcm and recieve it on the front end while the app is KILLED. Once the notification is received i want to fetch some data from the server and insert it into the local database. 
I am currently using react-native-firebase for notification, any help on the same would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Once the notification is received, you want to fetch relevant data and store them after opening the app or without opening the app?

Comment: Opening the app is not necessary. Every thing need to work while the app is killed.

Comment: Opening the app is not necessary. Every thing need to work while the app is killed.

Comment: Not going to happen. Notifications are received by the system when your app is not active. User can click notification to activate app but there is nothing you can do until they do. This is by design.

Comment: Can we use a background service of some sort to process the notification ?

Comment: Exactly as @Wainage says. As far as I know, there is nothing you can do until user opens the app. You can use background services such as background app refresh. But still app should be running in background.

Comment: ok. Thanks for all the help guys appreciate it.